# Issue Page loaded two time on blazor server side?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I work on blazor server side . I face Issue  page reload after open and reload automatically

so page loaded two times Why flicker happen on loaded page

and How to solve this issue

this not happen on one page this is happen on all application pages

sample code for page Dashboard happen this issue on it

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        
            await getcountServers();
            await getcountDatabases();
            await RefreshDropDownListFilter();
          
            await RefreshDropDownListOwnerFilter();
            await RefreshDropDownListDatabaseFilter();
            await SearchFilter();
            await GetFirstCharachter();
           
    }


protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
        {
            
            if (firstRender)
            {
                
            }

        }
```

on _Host file

```
@page "/"

<head>
   
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>UC.AppRepository.UI</title>
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_content/Radzen.Blazor/css/default-base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_content/Radzen.Blazor/css/default.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/assets/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="BlazorUI.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

    <script src="~/js/jquery-3.6.3.js"></script>
   
</head>
<body>
   
   
    
    
    
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />

       
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   @* <script src="_content/BlazorInputFile/inputfile.js"></script>*@
@*    <script src="~/assets/js/insertdata.js"></script>*@
    
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>

    <script src="_content/CurrieTechnologies.Razor.SweetAlert2/sweetAlert2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="_content/Radzen.Blazor/Radzen.Blazor.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.12/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/assets/js/downloadexcel.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/downloadexcel.js"></script>
      <script src="~/assets/js/checksessiontimeout.js"></script>
@*    <script src="~/js/checksessiontimeout.js"></script>*@
</body>
</html>
```

Page requests Dev tool Network Requests
[image: requests Dev Tools Network]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to modify RenderMode from `ServerPrerendered` to `Server`, and it can help prevent from executing twice.

```
<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="Server" />
```

Comment: and what about requests above can you please check if it have repeated requests

Comment: Based on your network requests, we can find that those are requests to some css and font etc static files, and some are accessed to local cached resources.

Comment: so how to solve this issue

Comment: The [static files are publicly available in the local cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/304), which is a normal behavior in web apps, that is not an issue. Besides to fix the issue about code executing twice, as I suggested, you can change RenderMode to Server.

Comment: ok are there are any recommendation on code can i do it

Comment: Have you tried above solution, and if it can help fix the issue about code executing twice?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253409/discussion-between-fei-han-and-ahmed-abdelaziz).